# Could not allocate CursorWindow. Error -24

Tags: android, android-cursor

This is the complete error message that I am getting. After this the app is crashing:

> Could not allocate CursorWindow
>   '/data/data/com.beta.android.beewise/databases/Roboto-Bold.ttf' of
>   size 2097152 due to error -24.

This scenario is not consistently reproducible. It happens only sometimes. Also, Roboto-Bold.ttf is one of the many fonts, which I have stored in assets/fonts/. I am also curious as to why only this particular font file is showing up here.

Comment: I have the same problem. E/CursorWindow: Could not allocate CursorWindow '/data/...foodanalyzer.db' of size 2097152 due to error -24. It doesn't happen all the time for me neither. It seems to either have to do with nonclosed cursor, or that the size of the data we are fetching from database is simply to large.

Comment: Is your database really named `Roboto-Bold.ttf`? Very interesting choice, very suspicious choice...